# Linq Average of bit (true percentage)?

Tags: c#, linq, average

I want to average the time of a bit value from my database.

So basicly it is:

```
ID 1, Value: True
ID 2, Value: False
ID 3, Value: True
```

So I want to have the Average of 66% Enabled time...

How to calculate that in linq?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Possibly the shortest way is:

```
double average = collection.Average(item => item.Value ? 1.0 : 0.0);
```

Comment: Nice, I'd forgotten about the overloads with the selector built in.

Comment: @MarcGravell - Thank :)

Answer (score 4):

Many ways to do it, here's one:

```
var pc = values
   .Select(v => v.Value ? 1f : 0f)
   .Average();
```

Keep your percentage values so that 1 == 100% so that they multiply nicely and use `P` to format them for display:

```
var pc = 2f/3f;
string.Format("{0:P0}", pc); // 67%
```

Or you will be forever multiplying and dividing by 100.

Comment: Since the question is about *per cents* (`66%`), probably it should be `...? 100f : 0f...`

Comment: @DmitryBychenko No, I strongly advise people to keep percentages as 1 = 100%. It should be easy to multiply and use in a string format: `string.Format("{0:P}", 1) = "100.00%"` The alternative is you will be forever multiplying and dividing by 100.

Comment: I see; `[0..1]`  range and final  *formatting* is, IMHO, the best solution; +1

Answer (score 2):

in LINQ? Untested, but probably something like:

```
var percent = source.Select(row => row.Value ? 1.0 : 0.0).Average();
```

You could also use `Count()` and `Count(x => x.Value)`, but that would presumably be two trips to the database.

Answer (score 0):

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    List<Foo> foos = new List<Foo>();
    foos.Add(new Foo() { ID = 1, Value = true });
    foos.Add(new Foo() { ID = 2, Value = false });
    foos.Add(new Foo() { ID = 3, Value = true });

    double Average = (foos.Count(F => F.Value) / Convert.ToDouble(foos.Count)) * 100;
}


public class Foo
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public bool Value { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: When the data source is presumably a database, it may be dangerous to use things like `Convert`. It *might* work, but it is really up to what the specific LINQ provider supports.

Answer (score 0):

This assumes that you have an `IEnumerable<bool>` that you're computing the average for:

```
// Just create some test data.
IEnumerable<bool> test = Enumerable.Range(0, 12).Select(x => x%3 == 0);

// Compute the average number of items that are true, as a %.
var average = 100 * test.Average(x => x ? 1.0 : 0.0);
```